# How do I set a min-height to an element that has a height of 100dvh

Tags: html, css, height

So I have a div with a background picture and it is set height: 100dvh;. It has a 2 child elements with some text and a button. So my problem is when a vh is smaller than those elements combine they flow out of the parent element. So I tried to set a min-height of a parent element to 400px, but it's not working.

You can still size your browser below 400px height, and button will be out of the parent element for example.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Please add your code as a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is set `100vh` as `min-height` to the parent container, so that it will take at least `100vh` of height. Then set actual `height` as `fit-content`, so it will expand as per the heights of its child elements.

```css
.parent {
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.child-one {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 1000px;
}

.child-two {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-one">
    first child
  </div>
  <div class="child-two">
    second child
  </div>
</div>
```